# How to post an object in postman without FromBody?

Tags: postman

Let's say my controller is taking an **object** parameter **without** [FromBody], how do I post the data using Postman? I tried this way but it doesn't reach the endpoint.

[image]

Comment: It seems you meant form body but you've written FromBody

Comment: "It doesn't reach the endpoint" is another thing,
It means your request is not delivered to your web-server and you need to check the logs, I think you meant this doesn't work properly, Can you tell me what's the "Content-Type" in your header tags?

Comment: @AMK, it is [FromBody] at the endpoint parameter. The backend is in ASP.NET

Comment: @Steve what is the API returning? a `404 Not Found`? `200 Ok`? --Also important check your routes, in the controller and in the action method. Also check your action method is decorated with the `[Post]` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this case, since you're not using **[fromBody]** your object should be in the URL and not in the Request Body.
in Postman, this can be done using the `Query Params` as the screenshot shows.

Yet, I don't think you could pass an object in the query params like that. I think you should instead turn it into a query string like this format

```
"User=abc&Pass=abc"
```

Multiple ways to achieve this can be found [here](https://howchoo.com/javascript/how-to-turn-an-object-into-query-string-parameters-in-javascript)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your controller is taking an object parameter **without** [FromBody] then you must send the data as URL parameter:

```
POST http://localhost:44364/login?object={"User":"abc","Pass":"abc"}
```

Note: replace "object" by the name of the parameter in your controller. Also you have to know that Postman should converts special characters { " : , to %XX format and you have to manage that in your service.

If you want to send it in the body, then include [FromBody]

Comment: @Steve The best is passing the json in the body, just like you have in the image you show in the question. Just remember to include [FromBody] in your controller.